# Can I use a regex capturing group to prevent successive matches of that group?

Tags: javascript, regex, l-systems

I have written a Javascript interpreter based on regular expressions. Is it possible to use capturing groups to prevent a successive match from evaluating any previously captured matches.

Example:
I start with a string `X`. Here are two replacement rules:

`X: 'F-[[X]+X]+F[+FX]-X'`

`F: 'FF'`

pass 0: 
`X` is replaced by `F-[[X]+X]+F[+FX]-X`. Since `F` is not in the initial string it is ignored.

pass 1: here is where I want to use a capture group strategy.
I first replace the 4 `X`s. Now, how do I ignore those matches - presumably using capturing groups - and only evaluate the rest of the string?

Comment: So, for example, you want a string of `XF` to turn into `F-[[X]+X]+F[+FX]-XFF` rather than `FF-[[X]+X]+FF[+FFX]-XFF`, is that it?

Comment: Show some intermediate steps. Like pass 1 in more detail. Normally to _ignore_ something, you have to _match_ it, then write it back. `((?:F-\[\[X\]+X\]+F\[+FX\]-X)*)|((?:(?!F-\[\[X\]+X\]+F\[+FX\]-X).)+)`

Comment: Indeed @CertainPerformance. I currently use a hack of adding a junk guard symbol that I discard after all matches are run. Your answer is just the ticket dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a single regex with a replacer function instead, one that replaces `x`s with the desired `x` replacement, and `f`s with the desired `f` replacement, so they're all done at once, no need to mess with capturing groups:

```js
const replacements = {
  X: 'F-[[X]+X]+F[+FX]-X',
  F: 'FF'
};
const doReplace = str => str.replace(/[XF]/g, match => replacements[match]);
const r1 = doReplace('X');
const r2 = doReplace(r1);
console.log(r1);
console.log(r2);
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much.